# Set DigitalOcean project in Terraform script

Tags: terraform, digital-ocean, infrastructure

I have terraform script for deploying and provisioning DigitalOcean droplets and I wanna specify custom DO project for this instances instead of default one.

I couldn't find any references for `project` attribute in the documentation for `digitalocean_droplet` resource: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/do/r/droplet.html

I wanna be able to do something like this:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "node" {
  ...
  project = "test"
  ...
}
```

So instances deployed with this terraform script will be allocated to `test` project in DO:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you are safe.

Nowdays you can do that as following:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "node" {
  name               = "ubuntu-nyc1-node-01"
  image              = "ubuntu-18-04-x64"
  region             = "nyc1"
  size               = "s-1vcpu-1gb"
  private_networking = true
}

resource "digitalocean_project" "project" {
  name        = "Project"
  description = "project description"
  purpose     = "Web Application"
  environment = "Production"
  resources   = [
      "${digitalocean_droplet.node.urn}"
    ]
}
```

Hope this code still can help you.

Answer (score 2):

DigitalOcean projects are not implemented in the Terraform  provider, yet. There's an open [feature request](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-digitalocean/issues/118) for it.

It will most likely be an extra Terraform `resource` as they are an extra API object. You then could add other resources either

- with `resource "digitalocean_project_resources" "project-a"` (reflecting [DigitalOcean's API](https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/v2/#assign-resources)) or
- directly in `resource "digitalocean_project" "a"` (as in [Ken Powers' issue comment](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-digitalocean/issues/118#issuecomment-451784997)).

That depends how it will be implemented, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the droplet in a project that already exist and not create a new one you can do the following:

```
data "digitalocean_project" "myproj" {
  name        = "myprojname"
}

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "mydroplet" {
  image  = "debian-11-x64"
  name   = "newVM"
  region = "fra1"
  size   = "s-1vcpu-1gb"
}

resource "digitalocean_project_resources" "terraform_rs" {
  project = data.digitalocean_project.myproj.id
  resources = [
     digitalocean_droplet.mydroplet.urn
  ]
}
```

This uses the `data` api to query DO and get your project, then you don't create a new project but create a new project resource which means you just assign the resource to the project. Hope this helps someone in the future.